# Save routine creates two rows in table...one blank except for comment and the other is fine?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a userform that when a user clicks a button, it opens a new Comment log form.  In this new form, I pull all the associated comments and display them in a subform/datasheet.

In this second form, I have a comment field to allow for the entry of a new comment.  When the user clicks the add button, they can enter text then click the save button, and the comment saves to the associated table

(I am preventing Edits and deletions on this second form...only additions allowed)

Everything seems fine and it works well, however, when I go to the table I'm appending to, there are two appended records for a single comment.  In both records, the comment text is present but in the first record, all other data elements are missing.  The second record is perfect.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
Private Sub AddNew_Click()
Me.Item_ID = Forms![F_First_Form]![ID]
Me.Item_Number = Forms![F_First_Form]![Item Number]
Me.Form_Name = "F_First_Form"
Me.User_ID = (Environ$("Username"))
Me.Comment.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.Item_ID = Forms![F_First_Form]![ID]
Me.Item_Number = Forms![F_First_Form]![Item Number]
Me.Form_Name = "F_First_Form"
Me.User_ID = (Environ$("Username"))
Me.AddNew.SetFocus
End Sub
Private Sub SaveComment_Click()
 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set rst = dbs.TableDefs("Conversation_Log").OpenRecordset
If Me.Comment = vbNullString Or Me.Dirty = False Then
Exit Sub
Else
With rst
.AddNew
!Form_Name = "F_First_Form"
    !User_ID = (Environ$("Username"))
!Item_Number = Me.Item_Number
!Item_ID = Me.Item_ID
!Comment = Me.Comment
.Update
End With
Me.Requery
Me.Refresh
MsgBox "Your comment has been saved"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you going to all this trouble? Why not just bind the forms to the relevant tables, or better, suitable queries? That way, you would not be adding the data twice.

Comment: I have it bound to a query so only the comments associated with the active item on the first form display.  My save button then adds the new comment with the static data I need (and have auto-populated) to the Comments table.  I then requery and refresh so the new comment shows in the datasheet subform

Comment: You're adding a new record `OnLoad` then adding another new record on `SaveComment_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the AddNew in the Form Load routine:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Item_ID = Forms![F_First_Form]![ID]
    Me.Item_Number = Forms![F_First_Form]![Item Number]
    Me.Form_Name = "F_First_Form"
    Me.User_ID = (Environ$("Username"))
    **'Me.AddNew.SetFocus**
```

End Sub